# How to check if any file exist in specific folder?

Tags: c++, windows, file, winapi, mfc

I am using `CreateProcess` to copy files. Also I can catch different errors, if PC is offline, if directory does not exist.
Here is the problem I have: It returns 0 as error code, if all copying is successful and also returns 0 if there were zero files in source folder, so no copying is done. I must detect whether there are no files in source folder. How can I do it in MFC VC++ 2013?

I have spent hours trying different solutions, but my knowledge is not high enough to implement all I find on internet. So I have to ask for code, then I will understand. Thank you in advance.

This is code I use:

```
temp_dest = _T("/min /c xcopy \"D:\\Test\\*.*\" \"") + m_destination + _T("\" /Y /E /Q");
LPTSTR temp_dest2 = (LPTSTR)(LPCTSTR)temp_dest;
STARTUPINFO            sinfo;
PROCESS_INFORMATION    pinfo;
memset(&sinfo, 0, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
memset(&pinfo, 0, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
sinfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
sinfo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
BOOL bSucess = CreateProcess(L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", temp_dest2, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE, NULL, NULL, &sinfo, &pinfo);
DWORD dwCode;
TerminateProcess(pinfo.hProcess, 2);
GetExitCodeProcess(pinfo.hProcess, &dwCode);
TCHAR msg2[100];
StringCbPrintf(msg2, 100, TEXT("%X"), dwCode); 
MessageBox(msg2, (LPCWSTR)L"DWCode 2", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
if (dwCode == 4)
{
    MessageBox((LPCWSTR)L"DW 4", (LPCWSTR)L"Path not found", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
}
if (dwCode == 2)
{
    MessageBox((LPCWSTR)L"DW 4", (LPCWSTR)L"PC Offline", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
}
```

Comment: c++17 has `<filesystem>` to copy from code instead of relying to external command.

Comment: This would be way simpler as a bat file. Any reason it needs to be in C++?

Comment: See if you can get away from `_T` and all that `TCHAR` messiness. Use the Unicode versions, rather than the current mix of Wide and T chars,  and be done with it. Fewer nasty surprises that way.

Comment: @rerun Its used with MFC dialog based app... so i can check and uncheck what to backup... i have like 30 PC's to run this command...

Comment: I don't get this. You terminate the process immediately, it doesn't have time to do anything.

Comment: *It returns 0 as error code, if all copying is successful and also returns 0 if there were zero files in source folder, so no copying is done.*  First, how is that a failure? There was no copying to do if there were no files in the source folder.  Second, your entire design is a [TOCTOU bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use).  What happens if any files get deleted after you've checked they exist?  What happens if files get added after you've found none?

Comment: "*I am using CreateProcess to copy files*" - Why? You can use `SHFileOperation()` or `IFileOperation` instead, there is no need to shell out to a separate process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the WIN32 function [GetFileAttributes(..)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa364944(v=vs.85).aspx) to check if a file exists or not:

```
if (GetFileAttributes("C:\\test.txt") != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES)
{
    /* C:\test.txt is existing */
}
```

Another way just might be trying to open the file (and if successful to close it again).

Comment: @Luke Thomsen Can I use GetFileAttributes somehow, if filenames are unknown? to use something like \*.\*

Comment: No you can't. If you want to search for patterns like *.* please have a look at the FindFirstFile(..) and FindNextFile(..) functions which allow you to search for existing files in a directory.

Comment: @Luke Thomsen OK, i got it now... i finally found it... since source paths are static, but filenames are dynamic, I can use this code
`WIN32_FIND_DATA findFileData; HANDLE hFind; hFind = FindFirstFile(L"C:\\*.*", &findFileData); if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) { MessageBox(findFileData.cFileName, (LPCWSTR)L"Fajl 1", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);}`

Comment: Note that it is *possible* (albeit *unlikely*) that `GetFileAttributes()` can fail with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` when the file exists but you don't have access to read its attributes. So you should check for that condition, eg: `if ((GetFileAttributes("C:\\test.txt") != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES) || (GetLastError() == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED))`  Same with opening the file.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for your info, but it is impossible (i think) to get acess denied because before copying, I am adding windows credentials for admin account 
`temp_cred = _T("/min /c cmdkey /add:PC_NAME.SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.local /user:admin /pass:text"); ShellExecute(GetSafeHwnd(),"open",L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",temp_cred,NULL,SW_HIDE);`

Comment: Why are you using `cmdkey` like that? In any case, you are executing a separate `cmd.exe` process to run `cmdkey`.  That will not have any effect on the `cmd.exe` process you are using to copy files. If you want to run `cmd.exe` with elevated rights, use the `"runas"` verb instead of `"open"`, and let it prompt the user for admin credentials. You can do the same thing with `xcopy` by using `ShellExecute()` instead of `CreateProcess()`.

Comment: With `ShellExecute()` I cannot catch dwError code, if no files are copied, it will just continue, that was not acceptable. I must be notified if someone deleted files, and this algorithm does that.

Answer (score 4):

If you can use `directory_iterator` from `<filesystem>` header file introduced in C++17:

```
bool IsEmptyDirectory( const wchar_t* dir )
{
    return std::filesystem::directory_iterator( std::filesystem::path( dir ) )
            == std::filesystem::directory_iterator();
}
```

*May be needed `std::experimental::filesystem` instead of `std::filesystem`*.

I have tried to port it to VC 2013, but only `char` version seems to compile

```
bool IsEmptyDirectory( const char* dir )
{
    return std::tr2::sys::directory_iterator( std::tr2::sys::path( dir ) )
            == std::tr2::sys::directory_iterator();
}
```

If you want (or have) to use WinAPI:

```
bool IsEmptyDirectory( const wchar_t* dir )
{
    wstring mask( dir);
    mask += L"\\*";

    WIN32_FIND_DATA data;
    HANDLE  find_handle = FindFirstFile( mask.c_str(), &data );
    if ( find_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
    {
        // Probably there is no directory with given path.
        // Pretend that it is empty.
        return true;
    }

    bool empty = true;
    do
    {
        // Any entry but . and .. means non empty folder.
        if ( wcscmp( data.cFileName, L"." ) != 0 && wcscmp( data.cFileName, L".." ) != 0 )
            empty = false;
    } while ( empty && FindNextFile( find_handle, &data ) );

    FindClose( find_handle );

    return empty;
}
```